# Is it legal to turn right on to the near lane of 4 lane road (two lanes per direction), when there is a vehicle on the far lane (USA)

Tags: usa, legal, driving, washington-state

Is it legal to turn right on to the near lane of 4 lane road (two lanes per direction), when there is a vehicle on the far lane or should I wait for the blue car to pass.

Location: USA, WA

[image: samplepic]

Comment: I wondered about that too, but I have seen police cars do it often (not being on emergency duty). I do it all the time, and nobody ever cared...

Comment: It is legal. But, it is not always a good idea. It depends on the road and the speed of the other car. Right turns onto a highway access road are a good examples of where you should take a conservative approach.

Answer (score 10):

You can and you are expected to turn into the nearest lane. Whether there is traffic in the other lane is apparently not relevant.

The [Washington State Driver Guide](https://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/docs/driverguide-en.pdf) says:

> Turn from the lane that is closest to the direction you want to go and turn into the lane closest to the one you came from. When making turns, go from one lane to the other as directly as possible without crossing lane lines or interfering with traffic. Once you have completed your turn, you can change to another lane if you need to.

That said, it's a very good idea to wait if you aren't absolutely sure that the driver of that vehicle isn't going to suddenly change lanes without signaling. Countless dashcam accident videos on YouTube taught me this... I'd go only if I saw him move from the right to the left lane to let me in.

Comment: Technically this is answering the question of which lane you need to turn it.  It does NOT address the question of WHEN it's legal to make such a turn (based on approaching traffic)

Comment: "**you are expected to turn into the nearest lane**" oh, if _only_ people would do this... Countless hours of my life spent sitting behind someone waiting for the _entire_ road to be clear so they can make a turn across _all_ lanes when there was a perfectly serviceable and _empty_ lane that they were _supposed_ be be turning into in the first place. The quality of US driver's education is abysmal at best... :(

Comment: Bear in mind that state and local laws govern traffic in the US. They tend to differ from jurisdiction to jurisdiction.